# Passing data to riot.js through ejs which is rendered by Node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, riot.js

I'm developing a web application which uses ejs and riot.js for server/client side rendering html.
What I want to ask is rendering data to riot.js through ejs from server. For this question, I prepared an example to render user's info on html.

Actually I could pass the data to html, but I couldn't have confidence my way which render information through ejs's javascript. If there are any better ways, please teach me.

**server.js (express)**

```
  router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    var user = {};
    if(req.user) {
      user.email = req.user.local.email;
    };
    res.render('login', { user: user })
  });
```

**index.ejs**

Passing to riot's custom tag with ejs. Is this way a good manner?

```
<html>
<body>
  <navbar></navbar>
    <script>
      riot.mount('navbar', { user: <%- JSON.stringify(user) %> });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**navbar.tag**

```
<navbar>
  <div>user's email: { user.email} </div>
  <script>
      this.user = opts.user
  </script>
</navbar>
```

**environment**

- node.js v5.3.0
- riot.js v2.3.12